# MMQGIS hub lines in QGIS python console

Tags: qgis, mmqgis

I'm working with QGIS 2.16.2 and I'm trying to use the MMQGIS hub lines plugin from the python console.
For some reason the output of the process only connects a few point in the hubs shapefile with a few point in the spokes shapefile.
Both shapefiles share point locations. 'centroids_distr1' contains a 'from_district' column with unique values from 1 to 12 and 'centroids_distr2' contains a 'to_district' column with repeated values from 1 to 12.

I'm new using python in QGIS so I don't know if it's a bug or it is that I am doing something the wrong way.
This is the code lines I'm using:

```
import processing
processing.runalg('qgis:hublines', 'C:/BUS/centroids_distr1.shp', 'from_district', 'C:/Documents_AGP/TUS/centroids_distr2.shp', 'to_district', 'C:/BUS/HubLines_TEST.shp')
```

Is there anything wrong?

Comment: BTW, it works as expected when executed from the tool's interface.

Answer (score 3):

You are not calling the algorithm from the **MMQGIS** plugin, instead you are calling a similar algorithm from the **Processing** plugin. Two separate and very useful plugins!

The algorithm from the **Processing** plugin does seem a little buggy as I can replicate your issue (might be a good idea to [submit a bug report](https://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis)). An alternative could be to call the `Distance to nearest hub` algorithm which has an option to create lines (however it only takes the fields from the *source* layer).

So you could use something like:

```
import processing
processing.runalg('qgis:distancetonearesthub', 'C:/BUS/centroids_distr1.shp', 'C:/Documents_AGP/TUS/centroids_distr2.shp', 'from_district', 1, 0, 'C:/BUS/HubLines_TEST.shp')
```

Comment: Definitely I was doing something wrong. Thanks for making me notice.

Comment: @DMS02 - Most welcome, glad it was helpful :)

Comment: I just checked **Distance to nearest hub**. It will only create lines linking each source point with its nearest destination point, and I want lines from each source point to all destination points. Anyway, the good news is that hub lines from the mmqgis plugin may still work. I'll search for that.